# [ARCore][Open3D] Depth and RGB registration

Tags: computer-vision, arcore, open3d

I am trying to run the reconstruction system in Open3D tutorials with RGB and Depth images captured using Android ARCore `acquireCameraImage` and `acquireDepthImage` on a Google Pixel 3.

Reconstruction system: http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/reconstruction_system/index.html

The images received from ARCore are of the following resolutions:

**RGB   : 640 x 480**
**Depth : 160 x 90**

These images cannot be input directly to the Open3D reconstruction system since it expects the RGB and Depth images to be of the same resolution.

I am researching currently how to convert the low resolution Depth image to the same resolution as the RGB image to input to the reconstruction system. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way to up-sample a depth image.
[Depth image super-resolution](https://paperswithcode.com/task/depth-map-super-resolution/codeless) is actually a research field.

How about down-sampling your color image to be the same resolution as depth?